# How does the parameter of the extension point "org.eclipse.ui.handlers" work?

Tags: eclipse

I define an extension

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler commandId="com.abc.test.command">
        <class class="com.abc.test.TestHandler">
            <parameter
                name="a"
                value="111">
            </parameter>
        </class>
    </handler>
</extension>
```

TestHandler

```java
public class TestHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Map parameters = event.getParameters() ;
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

When `TestHandler.execute(ExecutionEvent)` is called, the `parameters` is empty.
Why? How does it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExecutionEvent.getParameters` method returns the parameters defined using the `commandParameter` element of the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point defining the command.

For example:

```xml
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
           categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.category.window"
           defaultHandler="org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.handlers.OpenBundleResourceHandler"
           description="%command.openBundleResource.description"
           id="org.eclipse.ui.browser.openBundleResource"
           name="%command.openBundleResource.name">
        <commandParameter
               id="plugin"
               name="%commandParameter.openBundleResource.plugin.name"
               optional="true"/>
        <commandParameter
               id="path"
               name="%commandParameter.openBundleResource.path.name"
               optional="true"/>
      </command>
</extension>
```

The `parameter` element of `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` is only available to the class implementing the handler if it implements the `IExecutableExtension` interface. This has the single method:

```java
public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config, String propertyName, Object data) throws CoreException;
```

This gives the class access to the handler configuration element. In addition the parameter values are passed in the `data` object which will be a `java.util.Hashtable` containing the name, value pairs.

```java
@Override
public void setInitializationData(IConfigurationElement config, String propertyName, Object data)
    throws CoreException
{
  if (data instanceof Hashtable<?, ?> table) {
     var value = table.get("a");
  }
}
```